# Should git delete a file on master when one deletes it on a branch?

Tags: git

I am trying to delete some files in a branch, but I don't want those files deleted from master  or from other branches. However, when I delete a file on branchA, the same files are deleted on branchB and master.

This is not what I am expecting. I am expecting to still have the files on master and branchB.

So my questions are

a) Is this the expected behavior?
b) If not, what is going wrong?
c) Is something is going wrong, how do I fix it?

Comment: a) No, absolutely not. b) No idea, could you provide a minimal example (series of commands) that demonstrates the problem? c) Depends what the problem is :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment too, Thomas. As gmile suggested, the problem is that the files were not tracked by git at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you have: branch **A** and branch **B**.

If the file is being tracked by `git` and is present in both branches, then after deleting it from branch **A** it will remain on the branch **B**.

So the answer to you question is: **No, `git` shouldn't remove any file from a branch different to current.**

I have a suspicion that the file isn't tracked by git, and is listed under the "Untracked files" section of `git status`.

**Update**. If that's something possible to do – could you please include the output of `git status`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me check if the files are being tracked.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thanks so much.